# floating-ui/react-dom: Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'placement' before initialization

Tags: reactjs, next.js, floating-ui

I moved and extracted my `floating-ui/react-dom` code from one project to another project and now I am getting: `Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'placement' before initialization`

I do not understand why, the code is identical

here is my sandbox:
@floating-ui/react-dom: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/polished-waterfall-ilc51b?file=%2Fpackage.json [ This --> `https://ilc51b-3000.preview.csb.app/users/1` the sandbox page URL ]

I am using: `"@floating-ui/react-dom": "^0.6.2"`

Comment: In **components/user/profile/tabs/albums/JustifiedBox.js**, line 64 looks suspicious. You pass `placement` to `updateArrowClass`, but `placement` is not initialized until the `useFloating` function returns.

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code as text directly to the question, and [format it appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).